# Highlight formula in NetSuite that includes fields that are sometimes empty

Tags: netsuite

I’m having some issues with a highlight formula that includes fields that are sometimes empty.

I have a search that sums a few fields: field_A + field_B + field_C. The issue is that in some instances field C is either empty or has a value 0. So I’m trying to find a formula that says: if Field_C is empty, don’t use it in the calculation, otherwise use it. I was able to make the sum work on the search using this formula:

CASE WHEN {field_C} is NULL THEN To_char({field_A} + {field_B},'9,999,999.99') ELSE To_char({field_A} + {field_B} + {field_C},'9,999,999.99') END

My issue is when I try to highlight certain items on my search. Basically I’m comparing field_D to the sum of fields A through C. If field_D is higher by 10% then we’re underbudget, if it’s lower by 10% then we’re overbudget. However my formula does not work:

CASE WHEN {Field_C} is NULL THEN CASE WHEN 1.1*(max({Field_A}) + max({Field_B})) > sum({Field_D}) THEN 'OK' ELSE 'OVERBUDGET' END ELSE CASE WHEN 1.1*(max({Field_A}) + max({Field_B}) + max({Field_C})) > sum({Field_D}) THEN 'OK' ELSE 'OVERBUDGET' END END

Do you see anything incorrect in my formula? Do you have any idea on how to make this work?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this considerably by using the `NVL` function. Pretty much all the PL/SQL functions work in Netsuite formulaX fields -- they just are not documented in the NS documentation.

so the sum formula becomes:

```
NVL({field_A},0) + NVL({field_B},0) + NVL({field_C},0)
```

and the test becomes:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (sum(NVL({field_A},0) + NVL({field_B},0) + NVL({field_C},0) > 1.1* sum({Field_D}) THEN 'OVERBUDGET' 
  WHEN (sum(NVL({field_A},0) + NVL({field_B},0) + NVL({field_C},0) < 0.9* sum({field_D} THEN 'UNDERBUDGET' 
  ELSE 'OK' END
```

Note that these using aggregate functions in the formulas implies a summary value is selected for the row. So SUM for the first formula and any of min, max or average for the second. I don't know if it's been documented yet but any aggregate function in a formula field overrides those summary column selections and displays what is implied by the formula.